# Application tried to push a nil view controller on target in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, storyboard, didselectrowatindexpath

We have two `UIViewControllers`

- firstViewController
- SecondViewController

.When we click on `the UItableViewCell` we want it to segue to the `SecondViewController`.

We tried like this

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

   destinationController = [[UserDetails alloc] init];
   destinationController = (UserDetails *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"User"];
   destinationController.FriendlyName.text=[usernameFriendlyName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   UIBarButtonItem * backButton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:nil];
   destinationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationController animated:TRUE];
}
```

Please guide to us .What wrong in our code.

Comment: One thing is that you are not allocating your storyboard correctly. Try using the class method `storyboardWithName` to generate a storyboard from the correct storyboard file.. https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:

Comment: Obviously that storyboard is nil there

Comment: why are you doing this programmatically,  just use storyboards

Comment: You should probably read some book about Objective C before trying write something. Your ```storyboard``` is nil, hence sending message to it returns nil. You also instantiate ```destinationController ``` and overwrite it with no reason

Comment: @u.gen we need didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to do all this. Just connect the two viewControllers with the **Push** segue. **Give some identifier to segue**  and simply write this line in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"Your segue identifier" sender: self];
```

To pass data from one view to other use `PrepareForSegue` method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"Your segue identifier"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        YourViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [vc setMyObjectHere:object];
    }
}
```